# how to plot a node on osmnx with known latitude and longtitude

Tags: networkx, geopandas, osmnx

is there anyone know what is the relationship between ['x'], ['y'] and ['lon'] and ['lat']? If I know a node's ['lon'] and ['lat'], how I can plot this node on the street map?

I can use the G.node[22258] find the detail information of a node, like

```
{
'x':319101.513
'y': 4427916
'osmid':
'ref':
'lon':'-81.11861'
'lat':'39.982066'
}
```

But I would like to plot a node on the map. I know the latitude and longtitude of this node, but it seems I need to know the 'x' and 'y'.

Comment: If the tag `networkx` is relevant to your question, please add it.

Comment: Try this `ox.plot_graph_route(G, [22258])`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ox.get_nearest_node` to get the node from lat/long.

- Use `ox.get_nearest_node(G, (39.982066, -81.11861))` to get a nearest node
- Use `ox.plot_graph_route(G, [ox.get_nearest_node(G, (39.982066, -81.11861))])` to plot the node on map

Answer (score 0):

As far as my knowledge goes, x-y are projected coordinates while lat-long is geographic coordinates expressed in decimal degrees. The projected coordinates are dependent on the projection itself which varies from place to place. What is needed here, I believe, is a transformation of the lat long into the desired projected coordinate system.
Here is a piece of code that does this transformation (from WGS 84 to Spherical Mercator).

While these do not reveal your x and y, I am sure this is the sort of calculation one needs to apply to get their desired result. You may try out other projections relevant to, say the US. For example, I transform to epsg 3112 for Australia. When I do that, I can directly apply euclidian geometry to obtain distances in metres.

Links: https://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/wgs-84/, https://epsg.io/3857

```
from pyproj import Proj, transform

inProj = Proj(init='epsg:4326')
outProj = Proj(init='epsg:3857')
x1,y1 = -81.11861,39.982066
x2,y2 = transform(inProj,outProj,x1,y1)
print (x2,y2)
```

Output:

```
-9030082.35905815 4863336.501637128
```